# html mail receive of php form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

i am using this code for my PHP form where i have added too much fields 
i want to receive this form in HTML format while its comming in general message
also in mail should attached file.. which is also not coming
this is php back code is this

```
    <?php
/** CONFIGURATION OPTIONS
 * $email_address = The email address that all form submissions will be sent to
 * $company_address = The destination address that will be used in the contact form */
$email_address = 'info@synergywebdesigners.com';
$company_address = 'Delhi, India';
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
/** DO NOT EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE UNLESS YOU ARE COMFORTABLE WITH PHP */
echo "<script>var companyAddress = '".$company_address."';</script>";

$field_rules = array(
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|valid_email',
    'phone' => '',
    'contact_reason' => 'required',
    'message' => 'required'
);


$error_messages = array(
    'required' => 'This field is required',
    'valid_email' => 'Please enter a valid email address'
);


$error_list = '';


$fields = $_POST;



if (!empty($fields))
{
    //Validate each of the fields
foreach ($field_rules as $field => $rules)
{
    $rules = explode('|', $rules);

    foreach ($rules as $rule)
    {
        $result = null;

        if (isset($fields[$field]))
        {
            if (!empty($rule))
                $result = $rule($fields[$field]);

            if ($result === false)
            {
                $field_name = ucwords(implode(' ', explode('_', $field)));

                $error_list .= "<div class='error'>$field_name: " . $error_messages[$rule] . "</div>";
            }
        }
    }
}

if (empty($error_list))
{
    $subject = '[Application for Employment] New message from ' . $fields['name'] . '.';
    $content = $fields['name'] . " sent you a message from your contact form:\r\n\n";
    $content .= "-------\n" . $fields['message'] . "\r\n\n";
    $content .= "Position Applied For: " . $fields['positionapplied']
            . " \n\nTelephone Number: " . $fields['telephonenumber']
            . " \n\nMobile Number: " . $fields['mobilenumber']
            . " \n\nEmail: " . $fields['email']
            . " \n\nDate of Birth: " . $fields['bday']
            . " \n\nGender: " . $fields['gender']
            . " \n\nPermanent Address: " . $fields['permanentaddress']
            . " \n\nCity: " . $fields['city']
            . " \n\nState: " . $fields['state']
            . " \n\nPin: " . $fields['pin']
            . " \n\nMarital Status: " . $fields['marital_status']
            . " \n\nFather Name: " . $fields['fathername']
            . " \n\nFather Occupation: " . $fields['fatheroccupation']
            . " \n\nMother Name: " . $fields['mothername']
            . " \n\nMother Age: " . $fields['motherage']
            . " \n\nMother Occupation: " . $fields['motheroccupation']
            . " \n\nSpouse Name: " . $fields['spousename']
            . " \n\nSpouse Age: " . $fields['spouseage']
            . " \n\nSpouse Occupation: " . $fields['spouseoccupation']
            . " \n\nBrother Name: " . $fields['brothername']
            . " \n\nBrother Age: " . $fields['brotherage']
            . " \n\nBrother Occupation: " . $fields['brotheroccupation']
            . " \n\nSister Name: " . $fields['sistername']
            . " \n\nSister Age: " . $fields['sisterage']
            . " \n\nSister Occupation: " . $fields['sisteroccupation']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Course1: " . $fields['educationqualificationcourse1']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification University1: " . $fields['educationqualificationuniversity1']
            . " \n\nName of the College or School: " . $fields['nameofschool1']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Year From 1: " . $fields['educationqualificationyearfrom1']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Year to 1: " . $fields['educationqualificationyearto1']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Percentage 1: " . $fields['educationqualificationclasspercentage1']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Specialisation1: " . $fields['educationqualificationspecialisation1']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Course2: " . $fields['educationqualificationcourse2']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification University2: " . $fields['educationqualificationuniversity2']
            . " \n\nName of School2: " . $fields['nameofschool2']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Year from 2: " . $fields['educationqualificationyearfrom2']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Year to 2: " . $fields['educationqualificationyearto2']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Class Percentage 2: " . $fields['educationqualificationclasspercentage2']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Course3: " . $fields['educationqualificationspecialisation2']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Specialisation 2: " . $fields['educationqualificationspecialisation2']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Course 3: " . $fields['educationqualificationcourse3']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification University 3: " . $fields['educationqualificationuniversity3']
            . " \n\nName of School 3: " . $fields['nameofschool3']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Year from 3: " . $fields['educationqualificationyearfrom3']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Year To 3: " . $fields['educationqualificationyearto3']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification class Percentage 3: " . $fields['educationqualificationclasspercentage3']
            . " \n\nEducation Qualification Epecialisation 3: " . $fields['educationqualificationspecialisation3']
            . " \n\nComputer Proficiency Package Language: " . $fields['computerproficiencypackagelanguage']
            . " \n\nComputer Proficiency Excellent: " . $fields['computerproficiencyexcellent']
            . " \n\nComputer Proficiency Good: " . $fields['computerproficiencygood']
            . " \n\nComputer Proficiency Average: " . $fields['computerproficiencyaverage']
            . " \n\nProfessional Courses Programe 1: " . $fields['professionalcoursesprograme1']
            . " \n\nProfessional Courses Duration 1: " . $fields['professionalcoursesduration1']
            . " \n\nProfessional Courses year 1: " . $fields['professionalcoursesyear1']
            . " \n\nProfessional Courses Organised by 1: " . $fields['professionalcoursesorganisedby1']
            . " \n\nProfessional Courses Programe 2: " . $fields['professionalcoursesprograme2']
            . " \n\nProfessional Courses Duration 2: " . $fields['professionalcoursesduration2']
            . " \n\nProfessional Courses Year 2: " . $fields['professionalcoursesyear2']
            . " \n\nProfessional Courses Organised by 2: " . $fields['professionalcoursesorganisedby2']
            . " \n\n Employment Experience Name Address Organisation 1: " . $fields['employmentexpnameaddressorganisation1']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Name Year From 1: " . $fields['employmentexpnameyearfrom1']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Name Year to 1: " . $fields['employmentexpnameyearto1']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Position 1: " . $fields['employmentexpposition1']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Location 1: " . $fields['employmentexplocation1']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Reason Leaving 1: " . $fields['employmentexpreasonleaving1']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Name Address Organisation 2: " . $fields['employmentexpnameaddressorganisation2']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Name Year From 2: " . $fields['employmentexpnameyearfrom2']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Name Year To 2: " . $fields['employmentexpnameyearto2']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Position 2: " . $fields['employmentexpposition2']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Location 2: " . $fields['employmentexplocation2']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Reason Leaving 2: " . $fields['employmentexpreasonleaving2']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Name Address Organisation 3: " . $fields['employmentexpnameaddressorganisation3']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Name Year From 3: " . $fields['employmentexpnameyearfrom3']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Name Year To 3: " . $fields['employmentexpnameyearto3']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Position 3: " . $fields['employmentexpposition3']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Location 3: " . $fields['employmentexplocation3']
            . " \n\nEmployment Exp Reason Leaving 3: " . $fields['employmentexpreasonleaving3']
            . " \n\nCurrent Last Salary: " . $fields['currentlastsalary']
            . " \n\nReferences Name 1: " . $fields['referencesname1']
            . " \n\nReferences Designation 1: " . $fields['referencesdesignation1']
            . " \n\nReferences Company Name 1: " . $fields['referencescompanyname1']
            . " \n\nReferences Contact No 1: " . $fields['referencescontactno1']
            . " \n\nReferences Email Id 1: " . $fields['referencesemailid1']
            . " \n\nReferences Name 2: " . $fields['referencesname2']
            . " \n\nReferences Designation 2: " . $fields['referencesdesignation2']
            . " \n\nReferences Company Name 2: " . $fields['referencescompanyname2']
            . " \n\nReferences Contact No 2: " . $fields['referencescontactno2']
            . " \n\nReferences Email Id 2: " . $fields['referencesemailid2']
            . " \n\nReferences Name 1: " . $fields['referencesname1']
            . " \n\nFile: " . $fields['uploadField']
            . " \n\nSubmission Date: " . $fields['submissiondate'] . " \n\n";



    if (mail($email_address, $subject, $content, "From: " . $fields['email'] . "\r\nReply-To: " . $fields['email'] . "\r\nReturn-Path: " . $fields['email'] . "\r\n"))
    {

        echo "<h2 class='success'>Message Sent</h2>";
        echo "<br/><p class='success'>Thank you <strong>" . $fields['name'] . "</strong>, your message has been submitted and someone will contact you shortly.</p>";
    }
    else
    {

        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
}
```

}

function required($str, $val = false)
{

```
if (!is_array($str))
{
    $str = trim($str);
    return ($str == '') ? false : true;
}
else
{
    return (!empty($str));
}
```

}

```
    function valid_email($str)
    {
     return (!preg_match("/^(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22))(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))$/iD", $str)) ? false : true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing the code to send mail with PHP is a major pain, believe me I have spent hours trying to do it manually. You finally get it working and then, oh, Google thinks it is spam. Then another service thinks it is spam. Not worth your time. Therefore I strongly recommend using a service such as http://www.mailgun.com/ which offers 10,000 emails a month for free. Check out this tutorial to get started: http://blog.mailgun.com/php-how-to-use-mailgun-efficiently/. Trust me, you want to do this.

Comment: Hello Thestepafter... thanks for early responce. but at present i can't go for other.. Please give me solution for this

Comment: http://synergywebdesigners.com/safe/    this is the URL where i have updated Front end.. i am also not receiving attched file please give me the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't use mailgun, it is free to use and a form like you just showed me is very likely not going to get 10,000 submissions a month.  With that being said if you insist on sending mail manually without a 3rd party service I recommend using a PHP package such as: https://packagist.org/packages/nette/mail.

Comment: actually i have done everything for this form.. only 2 things still remainging.. which is file not attaching.. and mail receive should be in HTML formate... if you guide me how can i do this.. it will be good for me